# Error:flutter Unhandled Exception: type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String'

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

I got this problem for long time ago trying to resolve this issue I saw many places at internet but not able to solve this problem to get the info from the API call from the controller class. Because of this kind of error I saw in docs flutter maybe because the flutter package that is also a dart package I got the SDK 3.0.0 here's the code please someone to help me achieve this project thank you so much:

This is the model class:

```
class Product {
  int? _totalSize;
  int? _typeId;
  int? _offset;
  late List<ProductModel> _products;
  List<ProductModel> get products => _products;

  Product({required totalSize, required typeId,  required offset, required products}){
    this._totalSize = totalSize;
    this._typeId = typeId;
    this._offset = offset;
    this._products = products;
  }

  factory Product.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {

    var list = json['products'] as List;
    List<ProductModel> productsList = list.map((e) => ProductModel.fromJson(e as Map<String, dynamic>)).toList();

    return Product(
        totalSize : json['total_size'] as int,
        typeId : json['type_id'] as int,
        offset : json['offset'] as int,
        products: productsList
    );
  }
}

class ProductModel {
  int? id;
  String? name;
  String? description;
  int? price;
  int? stars;
  String? img;
  String? location;
  String? createdAt;
  String? updatedAt;
  int? typeId;

  ProductModel(
      {required this.id,
        required this.name,
        required this.description,
        required this.price,
        required this.stars,
        required this.img,
        required this.location,
        required this.createdAt,
        required this.updatedAt,
        required this.typeId});

  factory ProductModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return ProductModel(
        id: json['id'] as int,
        name: json['name'] as String,
        description: json['description'] as String,
        price: json['price'] as int,
        stars: json['stars'] as int,
        img: json['img'] as String,
        location: json['location'] as String,
        createdAt: json['createdAt'] as String,
        updatedAt: json['updatedAt'] as String,
        typeId: json['typeId'] as int
    );
  }
}
```

This is the controller class:

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:licores_app/data/repository/category_product_repo.dart';

import '../models/products_model.dart';

class CategoryProductController extends GetxController {
  final CategoryProductRepo categoryProductRepo;
  CategoryProductController({required this.categoryProductRepo});

  List<dynamic> _categoryProductList = [];

  // Get Method from Product Model
  List<dynamic> get CategoryProductList => _categoryProductList;

  // Response from repo product method
  Future<void> getCategoryProductList() async {
    Response response =  await categoryProductRepo.getCategoryProductList();

    print('got the products'); // This is right to this point

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      // Init to null not to repeat
      _categoryProductList = [];
      _categoryProductList.addAll(Product
          .fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body))
          .products); // --> Here the
      // Unhandled Exception: type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String'
      print(_categoryProductList);
      update();
    } else { // I added the curly braces but took off because I was 
       // debugging the problem still persist!
       print('not able to get product list json');
    }
  }
}
```

And this is the error:

```
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String'
E/flutter ( 6243): #0      CategoryProductController.getCategoryProductList (package:licores_app/controllers/category_product_controller.dart:27:72)
E/flutter ( 6243): <asynchronous suspension>
```

Comment: Are you sure you're getting a successful response from API? Because it seems like you're getting this error while trying to parse response from json.

Comment: You need to print out response.body and add this here then it will be quite obvious which field needs to be optional.

Answer (score 1):

You are accepting null data, so you dont need to force with `as`.

You can format like

```dart
   name: json['name']
```

```dart
  factory ProductModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return ProductModel(
        id: int.tryParse("${json['id']}"),
        name: json['name'],
        description: json['description'],
        price: int.tryParse("${json['price']}"),
        stars: json['stars'],
        img: json['img'],
        location: json['location'],
        createdAt: json['createdAt'],
        updatedAt: json['updatedAt'],
        typeId: int.tryParse("${json['typeId']}"));
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
factory ProductModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return ProductModel(
        id: json['id'] as int,
        name: json['name'] as String ?? '',
        description: json['description'] as String ?? '',
        price: json['price'] as int ?? '',
        stars: json['stars'] as int ?? '',
        img: json['img'] as String ?? '',
        location: json['location'] as String ?? '',
        createdAt: json['createdAt'] as String ?? '',
        updatedAt: json['updatedAt'] as String ?? '',
        typeId: json['typeId'] as int ?? 0
    );
  }
```

Comment: I did it but seems not working I don' t know I tried many things refactor the code and this was the best of all but seems not working once I tried to add the list of elements in the empty list what a problem! `_categoryProductList.addAll(Product
          .fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body)).products); ` Thank you but seems not fixed the problem yet.

Comment: @LanceDeal this is an elegant way to make sure you don't get runtime errors, even if your json object doesn't look the way you expected! However, your problem now is that you don't even GET a json object... And the above might actually mask that.  Because the json object SHOULD look the way you expect! So perhaps you WANT those errors, until it does... Or you could throw "Unexpected json object!" or something.

Comment: Yes absolutely  you right, Karolina, that is the main issue I don't GET a json object but it seems I was doing some research and trying to refactor  I little bit more to get what I spect I was doing it in so many small apps it was working but I don't know what happen with this one in particular.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, well add this to your code:

```
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      // Init to null not to repeat
      _categoryProductList = [];
       //Added lines:
       //----------------------------
       print('response.body is ${response.body}');
       print('of type: ${response.body.runtimeType}');
       print('jsonDecode(response.body) is ${jsonDecode(response.body)}');
       print('of type: ${jsonDecode(response.body).runtimeType}');
       print('Product.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body)) is ${Product.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body))}');
       print('of type: ${Product.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body)).runtimeType}');
       print('Product.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body).products is ${Product.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body)).products}');
       print('of type: ${Product.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body)).products.runtimeType}');
       //----------------------------
      _categoryProductList.addAll(Product
          .fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body))
          .products); // --> Here the
      // Unhandled Exception: type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String'
      print(_categoryProductList);
      update();
    } else { // I added the curly braces but took off because I was 
       // debugging the problem still persist!
       print('not able to get product list json');
    }
```

and tell me what it prints!

Comment: I took off curly braces just for debugging purposes the problem still persist.

Comment: @LanceDeal cool. Then plz see my updated answer above!

Comment: Well Karolina just skipped all the other code and follow straing to else statement `I/flutter ( 6243): Instance of 'Future<void>'
I/flutter ( 6243): not able to get product list json
I/flutter ( 6243): not able to get product list json`

Comment: That means you didn't get the status code 200. Then the rest of the code inside your `if()` doesn't matter! Check your API call and make sure you get a status code 200. THEN tell me what it prints from my added lines...

Comment: Btw, where does this "Instance of 'Future<void>'" come from...? When I check your code, the print just before your `if(response.statusCode == 200)` statement should be "got the products"... Did you get this output?

Comment: Hello Karolina well I have to check it tomorrow because I had a real ussue with my pc in the last 3 days ago and hade it to reinstall android studio and flutter so many times today  because emulator not working at all, so tomorrow let you know what will happen, if you still give me some more cooperation that will be really great thanks for now have a good night, before that the status code was not able to get it before these so many issues happen last week I was in the good path but now on I hope can able to fix this because it's work :(  .

Comment: I know it's terrible when Android Studio and emulators don't work properly...  You spend so much time on it, and you're not even working on your actual project! Anyway, I think your original error here (the one in the title) WAS because of the missing braces, as I said. That made the `if()` block code be executed even though the code wasn't 200. But the problem was never inside the `if()` block actually, it was with your IPA call.

Answer (score 1):

First you have to check are you getting response code 200. Then checked following way

First you make all fields in ProductModel class is optional (null acceptable).

then in constructor you have remove required work because you make it as option field, and in factory constructor there is no required an additional type casting like as Int, as String, just remove it.
After this you must varified all key in factory return class ( constructor of production class ). Simply i mean check your all key of json and verify further your all data type with json you received from Api or somewhere else.
Hope this will helpfull.

Comment: I did it but it didn't work because most of those solutions I did it all this error is somehow really challenging or maybe just still a small bug but as I told i did many things, refactor the code: remove required as you told it´'s optional fields, and the type casting I also removed still the problem persist thank you for your cooperation.

Answer (score 1):

You need to print out response.body and add this here then it will be quite obvious which field needs to be optional.

A statement such as this one:

```
img: json['img'] as String,
```

will produce the error message type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String' when the json object does not define the key 'img'

So one of the keys that you are parsing is undefined.

In order to figure out which one, we need to know what the response looks like exactly.

Then remove all the "as String" casts on fields that are optional from the server.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same exception with a class like:

```
class Place {
 final int id;
 final String name;
 final String? address; // <- This throws exception in factory Place.fromJson(....
}
```

and solved it like this:

```
class Place {
 final int id; 
 final String name; 
 final dynamic address; // <- HERE
}
```